# Palindrome number product of two 3-digit numbers - Project Euler Solution 4 - Brute Force not working

Tags: c#, numbers, palindrome

I am using this code to solve problem. 4 on Project Euler. The problem reads:

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>   Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

I have tried to solve the problem. My code returns a palindrome number and a fairly big one too. But it is incorrect. I have also found a correct solution at [MathBlog.dk](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-problem-3/). But what is wrong with my code? --

```
long result = 0;
for (long x = 100; x <= 999; x++)
{
    for (long y = 100; y <= 999; y++)
    {
        long num = x * y;
        if (num.ToString() == StringFunctions.ReverseString(num.ToString()))
        {
                result = num;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Result : {0}", result);
```

The `StringFunctions.RevereString` function is as follows:

```
public static class StringFunctions
{
    public static string ReverseString(string s)
    {
        string result = "";
        for (int i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            result += s.Substring(i, 1);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

My code returns `580085` but the correct answer is `906609`. I don't want to know about better solutions. I just want to know why **my** code isn't working.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never check whether the newly calculated result is greater than than the current result. It may be that you're overwriting your highest value result with a lower value in your for loops.

Comment: You are returning the **last** palindrome found, not the **biggest** one.

Comment: @rob and Dennis_E How could I even have missed that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Too bad you don't want to know about better solutions :-)

Comment: @Dennis_E that's because I have already found too many just by googling "Project Euler Solution to Problem 4". They solve the problem in ~0-1 ms. If you have an even better solution, I welcome you to let me know of it.

Comment: @FarhanAnam That makes sense. Solutions of the older problems can be found anywhere.

Comment: a faster way would be to start from 999 to 100. and the condintion `if (num > max && num.ToString() == num.Reversed)` will not check to reverse if num is smaller than biggest found number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is storing the last palindrome number obtained from the loop but not the largest one.

Both the variables `X` and `Y` iterate from 100 to 999

Imagine a case when (assuming all obtained numbers are palindromes) x = 500 and y = 500. It will execute earlier than x = 990 and y = 100. But in the earlier case the palindrome is larger but your code stores the smaller one. Use an if condition to get the largest palindrome:

```
long result = 0;
for (long x = 100; x <= 999; x++)
{
    for (long y = 100; y <= 999; y++)
    {
        long num = x * y;
        if (num.ToString() == StringFunctions.ReverseString(num.ToString()))
        {
            if(result < num)
            {
            result = num;
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Result : {0}", result);
```